# Spinners, intercept and check the default value

Tags: android, android-spinner

Hi guys I've been trying to retrieve the value of two spinners and make a simple operation based on the value of the selected item.

I've managed to retrieve the value and print it in a Toast message. 
The problem is that as soon as I launch the app the default value "Select Team" is presented in the Toast message.

To avoid that I've tried to intercept the value and print the toast message only if it's different than "Select Team", but it does not seem to work. The "if" statement is completely ignored.

Here is the code, considering that I'm new to Java and Android programming I would like to receive comments on other part of the code that might be improved.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Spinner sp_home;
Spinner sp_away;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sp_home = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_home_team);
    sp_away = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_away_team);


    sp_home.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                   int arg2, long arg3) {
            if (sp_home.getSelectedItem().toString() != "Select Team") {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), sp_home.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

    sp_away.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                   int arg2, long arg3) {
            if (sp_away.getSelectedItem().toString() != "Select Team") {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), sp_away.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

}



}
```

Thanks to everybody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is having issue

if (sp_away.getSelectedItem().toString() != "Select Team") {

Because in Java :

- == -> is a reference comparison, i.e. both objects point to the same memory location
- .equals() -> evaluates to the comparison of values in the objects

So while comparing string values always use equals and not == OR !=

Answer (score 1):

Use .equals() to compare strings, not == or !=.  .equals() checks the characters at each index.  == only checks the equality of the references, which will almost never work.

Answer (score 1):

to compare String in Android you have to use "equals"

```
if (!sp_home.getSelectedItem().toString().equals ("Select Team")) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
            sp_home.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```